Exercise 3.14b of Waterhouse Affine Group Schemes
I have been working on Exercise 3.14b of Waterhouse Introduction to Affine Group Schemes and want to make sure I am on the right track.

Suppose G is represented by A.  Write down the map $\varphi: A \longrightarrow A \otimes A$ corresponding to $\langle g,h \rangle \mapsto h^{-1}gh$.  Show it makes A into a comodule.

I viewed the above function $\langle g,h \rangle \mapsto h^{-1}gh$ as the composition $mult \circ (inv \circ pr_2 \times mult)$ and then obtained the corresponding Hopf Algebra map $(q \circ S, \Delta) \circ \Delta: A \longrightarrow A \otimes A$ where $\Delta$ and S are the comultiplication and antipodal maps respectively and $q:A \longrightarrow A \otimes A$ is defined by $q(a) = 1 \otimes a$.  Regarding the comodule part of the question, letting $p = (q \circ S, \Delta) \circ \Delta$, I have been able to verify the first condition that
$$
(id \otimes \epsilon)p = id.
$$
Letting $\Delta(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \otimes b_i$, we have that
$$
((id \otimes \epsilon)p)(a) = 
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(id \otimes \epsilon) \circ (q \circ S, \Delta)(a_i \otimes b_i) = 
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} (id \otimes \epsilon) ((q \circ S)(a_i) * \Delta(b_i)) =
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} (id \otimes \epsilon) (1 \otimes S(a_i) * \Delta(b_i)) =
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} (id \otimes \epsilon) (1 \otimes S(a_i))((id \otimes \epsilon) \circ \Delta)(b_i) =
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} (1 \otimes \epsilon(a_i))(b_i \otimes 1) = 
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\epsilon(a_i)b_i \otimes 1) = (\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\epsilon(a_i)b_i) \otimes 1) = a \otimes 1.
$$
However, for the second condition,
$$
(id \otimes \Delta)p = (p \otimes id)p,
$$
I have not been able to show equality.  Any help and or insight would be appreciated.  Thank you.
